# ORM and performance issues

Tags: orm

I'm thinking about learning ORM stuff but I think about one thing. If I have a table (or some joined tables) with millions of records, is it good to have mapped objects with millions of items? Is it safe to handle so big objects?

Thanks!

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545976/can-persistence-ignorance-scale

Comment: Are you talking from an object in memory holding millions of records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you will be doing with these objects; having a large number of them isn't by itself a reason to use ORM or not.

It might be more important to handle records in an object-oriented fashion so that business logic can be reliably performed on them.  Or conversely, if performance is a bigger issue then keeping things lighter might be preferable.  ORM is just a tool with its pros and cons; you need to decide if the benefits of using that tool outweigh the disadvantages.

Answer (score 1):

> is it good to have mapped objects with
>   millions of items ???

No, it's better to keep such relations unidirectional unless you have enough memory to hold all the rows in your RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to map m:n and n:1 relationship indeed car create performance issues.

That's why [fjorm](https://code.google.com/p/fjorm/) do not try to cache them ever. In fjorm, if you want to cache a table in memory, you explicitly annotate it with @FullCache.

Disclaimer: I'm an author of fjorm.